# Only Fiddler fixes my WININET GET request

Tags: c++, json, get, wininet

I need to send `WININET` request to rest server and get `json` response. Code works only while fiddler is working. I've tried everything what I've found but every time I get 0 into `bytesRead`. There aren't any errors and `HttpSendRequestand` and `InternetReadFile` both return true but buffer is still empty.

Server works fine and answers in a right way. When fiddler is running I get my 76 bytes, which I need. I tried to figure out using that blog [Help! Running Fiddler Fixes My App???](http://www.telerik.com/blogs/help!-running-fiddler-fixes-my-app-), no luck.

```
HINTERNET session = nullptr;
HINTERNET request = nullptr;
HINTERNET connect = nullptr;
BOOST_SCOPE_EXIT((&session)(&request)(&connect)) {
    if (request != nullptr)
        ::InternetCloseHandle(request);
    if (session != nullptr)
        ::InternetCloseHandle(session);
    if (connect != nullptr)
        ::InternetCloseHandle(connect);
} BOOST_SCOPE_EXIT_END;

try
{
    //std::wstring agent(L"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:40.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/40.1");
    std::wstring agent{ L"Mozilla/5.0 (compatible)" };
    session = ::InternetOpen(agent.c_str(), INTERNET_OPEN_TYPE_PRECONFIG, NULL, NULL, 0);

    if (!session)
        return;

    InternetSetStatusCallback(
        session,
        (INTERNET_STATUS_CALLBACK)IStatusCallback);

    connect = InternetConnect(
        session
        , serverName.c_str()
        , INTERNET_DEFAULT_HTTP_PORT
        , NULL
        , NULL
        , INTERNET_SERVICE_HTTP
        , 0
        , 1);

    if (!connect)
        return;

    //const wchar_t* parrAcceptTypes[] = { L"text/*", NULL };
    const wchar_t* parrAcceptTypes[] = { L"application/json", L"text/*", NULL };
    request = HttpOpenRequest(
        connect
        , L"GET"
        , virtualFolder.c_str()
        , L"HTTP/1.1"
        , NULL
        , parrAcceptTypes
        , /*INTERNET_FLAG_KEEP_CONNECTION*/INTERNET_FLAG_NO_CACHE_WRITE | INTERNET_FLAG_PRAGMA_NOCACHE
        , 1);

    std::string data;
    if (request)
    {
        BOOL isRequestComplete = HttpSendRequest(request, NULL, 0, NULL, 0);

        if (isRequestComplete)
        {
            const int dataSize = 1024;

            BYTE buff[dataSize];
            DWORD bytesRead = (DWORD)-1;
            BOOL bKeepReading = true;
            while (bKeepReading && bytesRead != 0)
            {
                bKeepReading = InternetReadFile(request, buff, sizeof(buff) - 1, &bytesRead);
                data.append((char*)buff, bytesRead);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            DWORD dwErr = GetLastError();
            InternetErrorDlg(parent_, request, dwErr, 0, NULL);
            LERR_ << "Request was failed. Error code: " << dwErr;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Replace _PRECONFIG with whatever the flag is for a direct connection? Run a lower level capture tool like Wireshark and compare a request with & without fiddler running?

Comment: When `InternetReadFile()` returns TRUE and `bytesRead` is 0, the end of the response has been reached. If the `buffer` does not receive the bytes you are expecting, the server is not sending what you are expecting it to send. Fiddler is likely altering your HTTP request headers in such a way that the server is responding as expected. For instance, maybe the server does not like the `User-Agent` you are sending, and Fiddler is changing the header to its own value. Some servers do send different responses for different `User-Agent` strings.

Comment: @Alex K. - I tried all types, INTERNET_OPEN_TYPE_DIRECT - doesn't help.

Comment: @Remy Lebeau you are right about response, I always get INTERNET_STATUS_RESPONSE_RECEIVED status, and I get it three times - 2 times for HttpSendRequest and then for InternetReadFile and I tried different User Agents - like "Firefox 2.0", "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 10.0; Windows NT 6.2; Trident/6.0)" with no luck